# How to exclude a string from a URL for filtering using regex

Tags: regex, google-analytics, regex-negation

I am trying to create a regex filter to include few URLs but exclude some of them. Here is the list I want to include and exclude
Include `/gr1/, /gr2/ , /gr2-usa-colors/ , /rucker/,/rucker-20l-usa/,/kr1/,/bullet-ruck/`

Exclude 
`/rucksacks/gr1/,/rucksacks/the-rucker/,/rucksacks/,/rucksacks/bullet-ruck/, /rucksacks/the-rucker/`

This is what I have tried so far but cannot figure out how to exclude the string "rucksacks"

````
```\/[kg](r[1-3]).|\/rucker.|\/bullet-ruck```
````

Note: I just want to include the URLs I mentioned above but do not include any other URL.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: If you are just trying to match any path that does not start with the "rucksacks" directory, then you could use a negative lookahead like `^\/(?!rucksacks).+`. If your requirements are more specific than that, then you need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess maybe,

```
^/(?:[kg]r[1-3][^/]*|rucker[^/]*|bullet-ruck)/$
```

might be working in there.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/xuxQal/1/)

Or if lookarounds are supported, maybe some expression similar to,

```
(?<!rucksacks)/(?:[kg]r[1-3][^/]*|rucker[^/]*|bullet-ruck)/
```

might be a choice.

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/X4QLR0/1/)